# How to set a specific chromosome in population for a genetic algorithm in DEAP Python

Tags: python, random, theano, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am using DEAP in Python and am using genetic algorithm there. The following is the definition of attributes(chromosome) with size of `100`.

`toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)`

The following expression creates a population with 300 sizes in which each individual column is a chromosome or a solution.

`pop = toolbox.population(n=300)`

My question is, how can I force `pop` to have a column (chromosome or solution) all `1`. I want to make sure that there is a solution with a vector of `1` in population.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def make_bool(x):
    return (x)

toolbox.register("bit_1", make_bool, 1)
toolbox.register("indiv_1", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.bit_1, 100)   

all_one = toolbox.indiv_1()
pop.append(all_one)
```